# Object values altered after return from function

Tags: c++, list, stl

PART OF A HOMEWORK PROBLEM

I have a list of objects, and my goal is to try and find if an object X is present in that list (I am interested only in the first occurrence of that object). My code seems to work fine for the most part, but I have this strange error where the value of only 1 particular object is being modified after it is returned from a function.

I added 10 objects to the list with values 0 through 3. When I search for any number except 0, (./a.out 1 OR ./a.out 2 and so on)I get the right output. But when I search for 0(./a.out 0), the findInList() prints the correct result, but the main() prints the value 18 (which is not even present in the list).

I am attaching the full source code here in case someone wants to compile it and try it out. I am also attaching the gdb step through I did.

SOURCE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

class Page {
public:
    int pgnum; // page number
    union {
        int lfu_count;
        int lru_clock:1; // can only be 0/1
        int lru_ref8:8;  // we only need 8 bits
    };

public:
    // Constructors
    Page(int num)       { pgnum = num; }
    Page()              {}

    // Operator overloading
    bool operator== (const Page &p) const { 
        if(p.pgnum == pgnum)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    bool operator!= (const Page &p) const { 
        return !(p==*this);
    }
};

ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, const Page &p) {
    os << "Page number: " << p.pgnum;
    return os;
}

// Think of this as an equivalent to equals in Java (IT IS NOT, JUST IMAGINE)
struct PageNumber: public binary_function< Page, Page, bool > {
    bool operator () ( const Page &p1, const Page &p2 ) const {
        return p1 == p2;
    }
};

// Function to find an object in any list given an Operation
template <class Operation, class T>
T* findInList( list<T> fullList, T obj, const Operation &op ) {
    T* ret = NULL;
    typename list<T>::iterator it = fullList.begin();
    it = find_if( it, fullList.end(), bind2nd( op, obj ) );
    if( it != fullList.end() ) {
        cout << "Found obj in list: " << *it << endl;
        ret = &(*it); // not the same as it (which is of type iterator)
    }
    return ret;
}

int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
    Page page_to_find;
    list<Page> frames;

    if( argc != 2 ) {
        cout << "Please enter 1 and only 1 argument" << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    page_to_find.pgnum = atoi(argv[1]);

    Page *p = new Page[10];
    for( int i=0; i<10; i++ ) {
        p[i].pgnum = i%4;
        frames.push_back(p[i]);
    }

    list<Page>::iterator it_frames = frames.begin();
    while( it_frames != frames.end() ) {
        cout << "Page in frames: " << *it_frames << endl;
        it_frames++;
    }

    Page* pg = findInList( frames, page_to_find, PageNumber() );
    if( pg != NULL )
        cout << "Found page: " << *pg << endl;

    delete[] p;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Normal `<` and `>` work fine, you don't have to use html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning the address of an object in a list that is pushed into the parameter list by value. Thus it is undefined behavior. Consider changing the parameter of the list in `findInList` to a reference.

```
// note reference type change in parameter list.
template <class Operation, class T>
T* findInList( list<T>& fullList, T obj, const Operation &op ) {
    T* ret = NULL;
    typename list<T>::iterator it = fullList.begin();
    it = find_if( it, fullList.end(), bind2nd( op, obj ) );
    if( it != fullList.end() ) {
        cout << "Found obj in list: " << *it << endl;
        ret = &(*it); // not the same as it (which is of type iterator)
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: damn! I understand the concept, but I don't understand why the output failed for only a single value.. Any idea?

Comment: @Neo I only see one call to that function from main(), the last thing in fact. Had it been called from anywhere else I'm sure the results would have been similar.